# keras how to replace load_data() method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# example of loading the mnist dataset
from keras.datasets.mnist import load_data
# load the images into memory
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = load_data()
```

In the above, how would I go about replacing the load_data method with my own images?

I'm assuming the X data is the image and the y data is the label, though I'm not sure how to package that for my own database.

Is it coming in a single file at a time or as a huge grid of images?

Comment: so,using `load_data()` will output 2 tuples each having `trainX` with shape `(60000,28,28)` and  `trainy` with shape `(60000,)` and the dtypes will be a numpy ndarray

Comment: This completely depends on what your data is, how it is stored, and how the labels are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you were right x is for images and y is for labels. The images are 28x28px in grey-scale and labels are ints from 0-9. [This page has more info.](https://keras.io/api/datasets/mnist/#load_data-function)

From what I can tell all you gotta do is import your images (using a module like PIL) either make sure images are 28x28 grey-scale before or do the processing in python. Convert images into numpy arrays and and than form an array shaped num_of_imagesx28x28. that array can than be passed on. For labels do a similar thing.

That would be my take on it...

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data), the file is saved as a `*.npz` file, which a filetype in which you can save several `numpy` arrays. You can read all about it [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html). For instance:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
outfile = TemporaryFile()
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)

np.savez(outfile, x, y)
_ = outfile.seek(0) # Only needed here to simulate closing & reopening file
npzfile = np.load(outfile)
```

```
npzfile['arr_0']
```

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

To answer your question, the `mnist` dataset you loaded is a single file, and it's called `mnist.npz`.